# Como manejar los datos obtenidos de json con php

Tags: php, json

Estuve haciendo pruebas para entender como manejar correctamente los datos obtenidos de un archivo `Json` y me encuentro con lo siguiente:
`Json`:

```
{
    "rates": {
    "AED": 3.673014,
    "AFN": 68.343295,
    "ALL": 115.9367,
    "AMD": 479.122298
}
```

si hago esto

```
$urlapi=file_get_contents('urljson');
    $data = json_decode($urlapi,true);

var_dump($data['rates']['AFN']);
```

me muestra uno en particular, yo me imagino que en este caso lo puedo solucionar con un `foreach`, más o menos:

```
foreach ($data as $precios) {
    print_r($data['rates'][?????]); 
}
```

Pero ahí debería modificar el subíndice para que mientras tenga elementos me muestre cada valor, en lugar del AFN que liste todos, me pueden explicar como se hace correctamente? Quisiera que me muestre cada valor y no le encuentro la vuelta.

Gracias!

Comment: a la estructura del json le falta una llave, ¿Así es o te faltó agregarlo en la pregunta?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si tu json viene construido así:

```
{
    "rates": {
    "AED": 3.673014,
    "AFN": 68.343295,
    "ALL": 115.9367,
    "AMD": 479.122298
    }
}
```

Puedes leer sólo los valores, o los valores y las claves.

Dado que es un JSON válido, puedes usar `json_decode` sin el parámetro `TRUE`, el cual se usa cuando quieres pasar el JSON a array. En este caso no es necesario, se evita manipular innecesariamente los datos y además la sintaxis de JSON (`$objeto->clave`) es mucho más clara que la de los arrays (`$objeto["clave"]`).

#### `Código:`[`ver Demo`](http://rextester.com/SMOII60185)

```
<?php 

    $datos='
    {
        "rates": {
        "AED": 3.673014,
        "AFN": 68.343295,
        "ALL": 115.9367,
        "AMD": 479.122298
        }
    }';


    #No le pasamos el parámetro TRUE porque podemos trabajarlo como JSON  
    $jsonObject = json_decode($datos);
    echo "------- Sólo valores -------\n\n";
    foreach ($jsonObject->rates as $v){
        echo "$v\n";
    }

    echo "\n\n------- Valores y claves -------\n\n";
    foreach ($jsonObject->rates as $k=>$v){
        echo "$k : $v\n";
    }

?>
```

#### `Resultado:`

```
------- Sólo valores -------

3.673014
68.343295
115.9367
479.122298


------- Valores y claves -------

AED : 3.673014
AFN : 68.343295
ALL : 115.9367
AMD : 479.122298
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero pues creo que tu json esta mal, verifica eso, porque no intentas realizar un var_dump de la variable $data, segun tu json quedaria algo como esto:

```
array('rates' => array('AED' => 3.673014, n => nvalor))
```

has esto:

```
foreach($data['rates'] as $key => $value) { 
    echo $value; 
 }
```

así te funcionara, si quieres saber mas del foreach te dejo [link](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: gracias por responder, en mi vardump de data me sale float(68.343295) y en el foreach que me decis vos me lista todos de maner float, 3.67309768.343295115.9367479.1222981.779852165.9175171.30930 etc